# PHP foreach loop help

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am working with a PHP foreach loop and I need it to output some specific HTML depending on which array value it is spitting out.

Everytime that the foreach loop hits a `$content['contentTitle']` I need it to insert a new table and then from there carry on. Essentially I want the for the loop to spit out a new table everytime a new contentTitle is found, but then add the rest of the data in the array as `tr` and `td`'s.

Comment: Could you please rewrite your question? It's totally incomprehensible. Also please provide some code or at least expected input/output.

Comment: *(hint)* there is no `array_spit()` and interpunctuation is not optional.

Comment: -1 because the only thing you can tell from your question is that you are using a table based layout. Learn to write HTML, __then__ learn to write PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `$content` is an element of some parent array, and that the first entry in that parent array does have a `contentTitle` entry, then you'd do something like this:

```
$first = true;
echo "<table>\n"; // start initial table
foreach ($stuff as $content) {
    if ($content['contentTitle']) {
        if (!$first) {
           // If this is NOT the $first run through, close the previous table
           $first = false; //... and set the sentinel to false
           echo "</table>\n";
        }
        // output the contentTitle
        echo <<<EOF
<h1>{$content['contentTitle']}</h1>

<table>

EOF;
    } else {
        // otherwise output the regular non-title content
        echo <<<EOF
<tr>
    <td>{$content['this']}</td>
    <td>{$content['that']}</td>
    <td>{$content['somethingelse']}</td>
</tr>

EOF;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, add an `if` condition inside of your loop. If it hits a $content['contentTitle'], then close previous table and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($content as $key=>$value){
  if($key == "contentTitle"){
    echo "<table>";
  }
  else{
    echo "<tr><td>";
  }
}
```